# What formula to use in Excel when trying to process dates

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, date-arithmetic

I have a Excel database and I have three columns. One is "holiday start date" and the other is "holiday end date" and "Available?" what I want to do is basically create a formula to see when the person is on holiday, the Available box will show Yes or No. The formula needs to recognise the date and only say that this person is not available if the holiday is within today to a fixed time. Anything else to become available.

I have tried over and over to try and get this formula but can't seem to get it to work here is my attempt so far.

`=IF(AND(AE9(DATE<=2/9/14),AE9(DATE<3/9/14),AF9(DATE>3/9/14)),"GOOD","BAD")`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the date effective in some cell. I am assuming this to be today for simplicity. If it is not, you simply have to replace today() with the cell number that has value for date effective!

I am also assuming the following headers on the following Cells. 

AE1 : **Holiday Start Date**

AF1 : **Holiday End Date**

=Today() : **Gives the current date**. Should be replaced with the date to be tested for!

`if(or(not(and(Today()<af9,today()>ae9)),today()<ae9,today()>af9,"no","yes")`

or simply

`if(and(today()>af9,today()<ae9),"yes","no")`

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have tried the formula and the outcome (Yes or No ) does not seem to change regardless of dates in the cells.

Comment: the dates change on a daily basis. holidays are added each day to different cells. they would simplily put "05/09/14" and in the next cell "10/09/14" so I cant seem to effectively work out a formula that will tell the user if that person is available, I understand that working out they "TODAY()" will logically work, but the formula does not seem to like it even when tested.

Comment: @pnuts no i am entering a date as a sting. not numbers. i am also formatting the cells to "short date"

Comment: @pnuts This does not work either. i have holiday dates in there that start on the 17th september and end on the 19th however it is saying they arent available. their holiday doesent start until that date so they are available up until then.

Comment: I am trying to put this in. do you have a full formula so i am putting it in the right place. Or shall i just copy and paste that into the cell?

Comment: @pnuts this is great the only thing is it doesn't work if their holiday is today. kind of like a >= rather than just <,> could this formula be manuipulated to show >= and <=? thanks a million

Comment: I have fixed it sorry.

Comment: hey @pnuts sorry for bringing this up after a while. but how about start date and end date both being today? That was the reason I had come up with a formula which works! even for a single day leave